Find entity by several key-value pairs in map
I have the following two tables office and office_attributes, where office_attributes contains key/value pairs for office.
Office:



id
user_id




1
1


2
1



Attributes:



id
office_id
key
value




1
1
a key
value1


2
1
another key
value2


3
2
a key
value1



Now I want to query the office that has the key/value pairs a key/value1 and another key/value2, this should return only the office with id 1 and not the office with id 2.
I've created a query now using INTERSECT, but is there a better solution for this problem?
SELECT * FROM office o WHERE o.id IN (
    SELECT o.id FROM office o LEFT JOIN office_attributes a WHERE a.key = 'a key' AND a.value = 'value1'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT o.id FROM office o LEFT JOIN office_attributes a WHERE a.key = 'another key' AND a.value = 'value2'
)


Please tag the database you are using?

You can JOIN office_attributes twice - once for each key/value pair you are looking for.You did not mention which database you are using, but I guess since the query involves simple JOIN, it should work with vast majority, do let us know if it does not.
Fiddle
SELECT o.id
FROM office o
INNER JOIN office_attributes a1
  ON o.id = a1.office_id AND a1.key = 'a key' AND a1.value = 'value1'
INNER JOIN office_attributes a2
  ON o.id = a2.office_id AND a2.key = 'another key' AND a2.value = 'value2'
;

The INTERSECT query you provided is missing joining condition, not sure if it was a typo, but a ON condition is needed before the WHERE.
    SELECT o.id FROM office o LEFT JOIN office_attributes a on o.id = a.office_id WHERE a.key = 'a key' AND a.value = 'value1'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT o.id FROM office o LEFT JOIN office_attributes a on o.id = a.office_id WHERE a.key = 'another key' AND a.value = 'value2'
;

